# Парсинг JSON ответ с сервера вида

Tags: java, json, gson

Подскажите как распарсить вот такой JSON. Дернуть отдельно объект `companies` получается без проблем, дернуть отдельную компанию по `Id` тоже не проблема, проблема вывести в цикле все компании.

```js
{
  "companies": {
    "3": {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "name1",
      "phone": "8888888",
      "total-houses": 5,
      "logo": "",
      "background": "",
      "sort": 4
    },
    "5": {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "name2",
      "phone": "77777777",
      "total-houses": 4,
      "logo": "",
      "background": "",
      "sort": 6
    },
    "13": {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "name3",
      "phone": "66666666",
      "total-houses": 7,
      "logo": "",
      "background": "",
      "sort": 7
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно не самый удачный вариант, но вроде работает:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Получаем внутриности элемента companies
    JsonElement cElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
    String companiesString = cElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().toString();

    // Создаем итератор по этим компаниям
    JsonElement copanies = new JsonParser().parse(companiesString);
    Iterator companiesIterator = copanies.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator();

    // Проверяем, что все работает
    while(companiesIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(companiesIterator.next());
    }
}
```